# Ubuntu Command Line Reports PHP version as 5.3.3 but phpinfo says 5.5.9

Tags: php, ubuntu

When I look at a phpinfo page on my ubuntu server it says the php version is 5.5.9.  But when I do a php -i or -v from command line it says php version 5.3.3 and it doesn't list the modules I've installed in 5.5.9.

I guess I have two versions running.  How do I get rid of 5.3.3 so command line reports 5.5.9?

Answer (score 2):

Do a `locate bin/php` to see all files on your system that might possibly be PHP binaries. Then do a `which php` to see which one would be executed. I have one in `/usr/bin/php` and a self-compiled version in `/usr/local/bin/php53`, of varying versions.

To run things on the command line with the other version, you can specify the full path of PHP thus: `/usr/local/bin/php /command/to/run` and it will run that. Or, add the path to the new version to your system path at the start, and this will "see" the new PHP version before the old one.

If you are running this thing from cron, I tend to recommend using the full path to the PHP interpreter anyway - I think it's a good habit, in case the available paths are different between your environment and the cron environment.

Comment: Great! Don't forget to mark it as solved - it takes it out of the 'unanswered questions' lists.